# Beginning jQuery: JQuery ID Selector usage

Tags: jquery

Beginning jQuery question. Here's the  code...

```
        var control1= document.getElementById("Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt");
        var control2 = $("#Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt");
```

Why doesn't the second debug print evaluate the same as the first?

```
? control1.id
"Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt"
? control2.id
undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var control1 = document.getElementById("..."); // returns HTML DOM Object
var control2 = $("..."); // returns JQuery Object
```

To get the `id` you can use

```
var id = control1.id; // or
var id = control2.attr("id");  // or
var id = control2[0].id;
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, to access the id attribute for display, the syntax is:

```
control2.attr("id");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

It's a jQuery element now so if you want the id of it, you would do:

control2.attr("id")

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `$("#Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt")` is actually a jQuery object, which functions somewhat like an array.  This is especially useful if you are selecting elements with a certain class name like this: `$(".className")`.

So to get the first DOM element found by a selector use this:

```
$("#Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt")[0];
```

Then you will be able to get the id property:

```
$("#Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt")[0].id;
```

However, it's much simpler just to use the `.attr()` method:

```
$("#Carbs_txtSubsContrRbtAmt").attr("id");
```

If the selector matches more than one element, the id of the first one matched will be returned by the above code.